# Raw unformatted text from postgres text field without psql flags

Tags: postgresql

I need to put a file in its entirety into a postgres text field and then pull it back out to eventually re-create the file on disk. For example I can put

```
{"generation":1,"count":2}
{"generation":2,"count":3}
{"generation":2,"count":3}
```

Into my DB:

```
  SQL (7.4ms)  INSERT INTO "data_dumps" ("data", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["data", "    {\"generation\":1,\"count\":2}\n    {\"generation\":2,\"count\":3}\n    {\"generation\":2,\"count\":3}\n"], ["created_at", "2015-10-14 21:03:40.019299"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-14 21:03:40.019299"]]
   (13.3ms)  COMMIT
```

However when I query it from the command line each row is munged into a single line. So this:

```
$ echo 'COPY (SELECT  "data_dumps"."data" FROM "data_dumps"  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1) TO STDOUT' | psql triage_development > tmp/test; cat tmp/test
```

Gives me the output

```
    {"generation":1,"count":2}\n    {"generation":2,"count":3}\n    {"generation":2,"count":3}\n
```

I cannot use psql flags.

My question is this: how can I have postgres to output a single large text field without headers and with support for multi line output?

Comment: Is that JSON you want to save?

Comment: Have you tried `$ echo 'COPY (SELECT  "data_dumps"."data" FROM "data_dumps"  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1) TO STDOUT with CSV' | psql triage_development > tmp/test; echo $(cat tmp/test)`? It should print it as multiline output. For the result without headers, I normally use `psql -A -t -q ...`

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto it's a Ruby Heap dump. Each line is a json blob, with many many lines. About 15 GB of text.

Comment: @FernandoÁ. I can't use flags because this will eventually be run through `$ heroku pg:psql` which doesn't support them.

Comment: @Schneems if you can't use these *useful* flags because your tools forbid their use, maybe you should reconsider your tools.

Comment: @wildplasser thanks for the consideration, I want to work within the constraints of this problem. Are you suggesting it isn't possible without flags or merely being snarky?

Comment: @Schneems: please update your question with the "contraints of the problem".  As it is expressed now, just adding `-At` behind `psql` answers it.

Comment: BTW you shouldn't even use `COPY` but directly `SELECT`. `COPY` has its own format with backslashes that you don't want or need here.

Comment: @DanielVérité question is updated. i'm using `COPY` to get rid of the headers, is there another way to get rid of headers without flags or `COPY`?